# Using Python to translate Excel --> Dictionary --> Excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to create a dictionary from an excel file, which I can use to write to a new excel file.

For example, if data is organized as follows:

```
Subject Date     Measurement
134     1/20/09  22
134     2/21/10  25
134     2/22/13  34
134     1/5/15   33
211     2/23/00  34
211     3/5/09   33
```

I would like to create a dictionary which outputs:

```
{134: {1/20/09: 22, 2/21/10: 25, etc}, 211: {2/23/00:34, 3/05/09:33}}
```

From this dictionary, I would like to write a new cvs or excel which organizes data as follows:

```
subject average measurement
134     28.5
211     33.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old now but it may interest someone. This code works:

```
# you need pandas library in my code but it's not the only possibility
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.parser import parse # for the date format

# your path
path_file_xl = "your\path\to\your\file.xlsx"
# Create a DataFrame (DF)
df = pd.read_excel(path_file_xl)

# Create the dictionnay
dict_data = {} # create an empty dictionary 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # If the subject not already in dict_data
    if int(row[0]) not in dict_data.keys():
        dict_data[int(row[0])] = {} # create the key
    # Add the new entry in the the dictionary linked to the subject
    dict_data[int(row[0])].update({ parse(row[1]): float(row[2]) })

# Create the table with average
table = [] #empty list to append data
for subject in dict_data.keys(): # for each subject in your dict_data
    # Calculate the average sum divided by length
    average_subject = sum(dict_data[subject].values())/len(dict_data[subject])
    table.append([subject, average_subject]) #append in the table

# create a DF with average data
df_out = pd.DataFrame(table)
# Rename and sort values
df_out = df_out.rename(columns={0: 'Subject', 1: 'average measurement'}).sort_values(['Subject'])
# write into a csv without the index of the DF
path_file_csv = "your\path\to\your\file.csv"
df_out.to_csv(path_file_csv, index = False)
```

There is probably another way without table feeding directly a pandas DF.